# Simple Probability Question: Odds are 2 to 1

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> The odds are two to one that, when A and B play tennis, A wins. Suppose that A and B play two matches. What is the probability that A wins at least one match?

The answer says that the sample space of this experiment is:

> E1: AA, E2: AB, E3: BA, E4: BB

I do not understand how player A can play against player A. I thought the sample space would have to be this:

> E1: AB, E2: BA

Also what exactly does it mean that `the odds are two to one that, when A and B play tennis, A wins`. The book uses this statement to find the probability of each of those Events (E1 to E4) as follows:

> P(E1) = 4/9, P(E2) = 2/9, P(E3) = 2/9, P(E4) = 1/9

I am not able to understand how they came up with these probabilities based on the fact that the odds are two to one. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The chances are $a$ to $b$ that A wins means that on average A wins $a$ games and does not win $b$ games out of $a+b$ games on average. This means that the probability that A wins is $\frac{a}{a+b}$ and that it does no win (and therefore  B wins because there is no draw in tennis) is $\frac{b}{a+b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample space $AA, AB, BA, BB$ is referring to who wins each game.  There is a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance that $A$ will win any particular game.  Since these are independent events, the chance that $A$ wins both games is $\frac{2}{3} \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$, etc. So, the chance that $A$ wins at least one game is $1 - P(E_4) = \frac{8}{9}$.

Comment: Ohh ok. So the fact that it say `The odds are two to one that, when A and B play tennis, A wins` It means that assuming they play 3 games, player A will win (2/3). Is that how you got the 2/3 chance I am still a little confused?

Comment: It means in any particular game, $A$ will win it $2/3$ of the time.  Think of flipping a weighted coin of the same odds. $2/3$ of the time it will come up heads, and $1/3$ of the time it will come up tails.

Comment: So A has twice the probability of winning correct? I don't understand how you got 2/3 from that information. Can't you also say A will win 1/2 of the time and B will 1/4 of the time. Since technically in this case A has a 2 to 1 chance as well. I am very bad at this type of math sorry.

Comment: The odds are "2 to 1".  Thinking about it this way, that means we are dividing 100% into three separate parts.  We can't have $A$ winning $1/2$ of the time and $B$ $1/4$ of the time, because then where is the other missing $1/4$?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Convert odds to probability; the formula is ratio/1+ratio:

2:1 odds  = (2/1) / (1+2/1) = 2/1 / 3/1 = 2/1 * 1/3 = 2/3

2/3 is the probability that player A wins a match, therefore 1/3 (1-2/3) is the probability that player B wins a match.

"Also what exactly does it mean that the odds are two to one that, when A and B play tennis, A wins"

All it means is that player A is seen as the better player and has a better chance of winning a match.  For every three matches played (in theory) A would win two matches and B would win 1.

After two matches you can have the following results:

Player A wins both matches: AA

Player A wins the first match, player B wins the second match: AB

Player B wins the first match, player A wins the second match: BA

Player B wins both matches: BB

Now just substitute the probabilities which were calculated based on the odds and you have answered your other question "I am not able to understand how they came up with these probabilities based on the fact that the odds are two to one."

AA = 2/3 * 2/3 = 4/9

AB = 2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9

BA = 2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9

BB = 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/9

With that you can answer the original question: "What is the probability that A wins at least one match?"

Method 1:  Just add up the probabilities where A is included

AA + AB + BA = 4/9 + 2/9 + 2/9 = 8/9

Method 2:  Just find the probabilities where A is NOT include and subtract from 1

1 - BB = 1 - 1/9 = 9/9 - 1/9 = 8/9